# XCode won't shake off residual memory of a renamed static library

Tags: xcode

I have a workspace that contains a project and a static library.

The library was called A originally and then I renamed it to B. However I changed my mind a little later and renamed it back to A.

The trouble is now that Xcode only lists liblB.a in Link Binary With Libraries and I simply cannot get this to go away and for liblA.a to reappear, even though I have renamed it back to A.

Within XCode the name of the target is A, also the name of the Product Name in the Build Settings is A. I don't have any references to anything named B anywhere anymore AFAIK or that I can find.

I've cleaned everything and cleaned again, deleted Derived Data in Organizer, closed and restarted XCode (which is an amazingly effective way to usually solve issues like this).

When I build the library it builds sucessfully and XCode say "Build A: Succeeded", it doesn't say "Build B: Succeeded".

I've seen this sort of problem before where XCode has problems shaking off references to things that no longer exist, and the usual solution is just to do a clean and a close of XCode. But that's not working this time. Any other suggestions on how to get XCode to forget about the name B and stack picking up A?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Commit your code
- Close Xcode
- Open the xcodeproj file with your favorite text editor
- Find all references to the undesired name and delete them or change them to the desired name
- Open Xcode and test
- If everything works, commit your code. Otherwise, revert and try again a little more carefully.

Generally, simple hand-editing the xcodeproj works fine, particularly to just rename or remove things. It's harder to add new stuff.